# In Amazon Redshift, how can I bulk insert rows only if they don't already exist?

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Redshift, I am doing a bulk insert of values into a table. However I only want to insert the values in this list that do not already exist in the table, to avoid adding dupes.

`INSERT INTO $TEST_TABLE values
(A, 1),
(B, 2),
(C, 3)`

If table already contains(A, 1), I want the statement to only insert (B, 2) and (C, 3).

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is **no automatic way** to only insert only non-existent rows (often called UPSERT = Update existing rows, insert new rows).

You could **load the data into a temporary table**, then do a command like this to only insert rows that aren't there:

```
INSERT INTO target
SELECT * FROM temp
WHERE temp.primary_key NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT primary_key FROM target)
```

If desired, a similar method can be used to also Update values where they already exist.

Comment: Hi, how should I write if I have a compound primary key? INSERT INTO target
SELECT * FROM temp
WHERE temp.primary_key NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT primary_key FROM target) AND temp.primary_key_2 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT primary_key_2 FROM target)

Comment: @AndrewLam Please ask a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.